# voting system increment votes

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, increment, voting-system

```
if (vote1 == 1) {
    result[0] = result[0] + 1;
    i.println(pres1 + " " + result[0]);
}
```

my if statement are up to 4 (eg: `else if (vote1==2...3...4)`). every time i choose multiple candidates, the result will get wrong and sometimes, the output will change. i want that every time i choose candidate 1, his votes will increment and also when i choose other candidates without any changes in the output.

eg:

```
candidate 1 = 8 (and increment)
candidate 2 = 3 (and increment)
candidate 3 = 5 (and increment)
candidate 4 = 6 (and increment)
```

please can someone help i really need it for my project

Comment: sounds like a homework :/

Comment: @StinePike [So, what is the problem with homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/161469)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to increment for **multiple** candidates, you need some sort of a loop to update the vote of each candidate:

```
int nbCandidates = 4;
int[] result = new int[nbCandidates];

// assuming you want to increment candidate 1, 3 and 4
// contained in an array
int[] candidatesToUpvote = {1,3,4};
for (int c : candidatesToUpvote) {
   result[c-1] += 1;
}
```

Here I assume that the candidate is identified by a number between [1,4]. Since array indexes start at 0 in Java, you have to translate from id to index with `(id - 1)`.

There are more robust solutions with a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the candidate id, and the value will be the vote value.

Comment: hey! i tried your suggestion and it really worked! thank you so much for that! but my problem now is that the output. i'm storing it in a text file and the output goes like this:
candidate1 1 (<number of votes)
candidate1 2
candidate2 1
candidate2 2
can you give me a solution that the only thing that will change is the number of votes and the names of candidate will just stay the same and won't add up another names and its new votes? it will be a great help thank you again!

Comment: If there is no concurrency in your app, you can manage to load the full file before a computation, then write the full data _without_ appending. But if you want to go further, you certainly need a database, like `mysql`. This is more complex but the power, flexibility and robustness is much greater than managing simple files.

Answer (score 0):

If your vote is value from 1,2,3,4 - you can simply use the following for each vote:

```
result[vote-1]++;
```

The idea is you use the fact that vote is a value in the correct range (verify it first!), and then you use this value as an offset of your array, and increment the relevant entry.